# Unable to sort the elastic search data in using nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, youtube-api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am getting the data from the elastic search but on using the sort query on the elastic data it is not sorting instead it is returning the data in the sort bucket.

```
sort: [
        {
          'statistics.viewCount.keyword': {
            order: 'desc'
          }
        }
      ]
```

the output I was expecting the sort the viewCount but Instead got the without sorting of the view count

Comment: Please join your mappings + a full querry exemple with 2 documents.

Comment: my query is dynamically mapped @LeBigCat, So how can sort a string data without mapping and I placed .keyword to the doc that I want to sort but it is not happing any reference available for the .keyword sorting?

Comment: @santoshkumar can you add a sample of your result data? you can [edit] your question add add the information asked by user LeBigCat and myself, of course. it is hard to try reproduce your problem if you don't provide the needed information. Please read: **[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.